# Solve for $ x$, $-\frac{1}{2}x^2 + 2x + 5 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I'm having trouble solving this equation for $x$:

$$-\frac{1}{2}x^2 + 2x + 5 = 0$$

What's the steps to take to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: The equation in the question..

Comment: Not sure how to format properly? It should be -1/2

Comment: @Cypras: the equation is not written properly and it is not clear what you meant as the LaTex is a bit hosed. Regards

Comment: Are you familiar with the quadratic formula?

Comment: Multiply by -2 and use the ABC formula

Comment: @Cypras, have you ever heard about Bhaskara?

Comment: No I haven't. What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x^2-4x-10=0$$
$$x^2-2\cdot x\cdot2+2^2-2^2-10=0$$
$$x^2-2\cdot x\cdot2+2^2=4+10$$
$$(x-2)^2=14$$
$$x-2=\pm \sqrt{14}$$
$$x=2\pm \sqrt{14}$$

Comment: +1 simple but leading approach.

Comment: @Thank you very much Babak.

Answer (score 2):

If you multiply by $-2$ you get $x^2-4x-10=0$, then you can use the [quadratic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula#Quadratic_formula) to get $x=\frac 12 (4 \pm \sqrt {16+40})=2 \pm \sqrt {14}$

Comment: How did you get 14?

Comment: sqrt(16 + 40) = sqrt(56) = sqrt(2 * 2 * 14) =  2 * sqrt(14)

Comment: @oks:  I am not sure OP will see your comment.  You can preface it with <at>Cypras as  Rustyn Yazdanpour did to make sure s/he does.  You can only notify one user with the at sign per comment.

Comment: @Rustyn That makes no sense to me. Square root of 56 equals 7.4something? How do you change it like that?

Comment: @Cypras:  Rustyn Yazdanpour is doing arithmetic under the square root sign, then using the fact that $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt a \cdot \sqrt b$.  The $40$ in the next to last should be $14$.

Comment: @Cypras $\sqrt{16 + 40} = \sqrt{56} = \sqrt{4\cdot 14} = \sqrt{2^2\cdot 14} = \sqrt{2^2}\sqrt{14}=2\sqrt{14}$, whoops

Answer (score 2):

If you multiply 
$$-\frac{1}{2}x^2 + 2x + 5 = 0\tag{1}$$

by $-2$ you get $$x^2-4x-10=0$$ Using the [**quadratic formula**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula#Quadratic_formula): $$ax^2 + bx + c = 0 \iff x = \frac{1}{2a}\left(-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}\right),$$ where in this case, $a = 1,\;b= -4,\; c = -10$ we have $$x=\frac 12 (4 \pm \sqrt {16+40})=2 \pm \sqrt {14}\tag{2}$$

Walking through the simplification of $(2)$

$$x = \frac12 (4 \pm \sqrt{16 + 40}) \;=\; \frac12(4 \pm \sqrt{56})\; = \;\frac12 (4 \pm \sqrt{4\cdot 14}) \;=\; \frac12 (4 \pm \sqrt{4}\sqrt{14})\;$$ $$ = \;\frac12 (4 \pm 2\sqrt{14})\;=\; \frac 12 \cdot 4 \pm \frac12 \cdot 2\sqrt{14}\;\; = \;\;2 \pm \sqrt{14}$$

Comment: We, here, denote the discriminate by $\Delta=b^2-4ac$. +